# Regex pattern matching takes a long time for strings with length more than 30 chars

Tags: java, regex, spring

In Spring `@Pattern` Annotation with the regex `^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+ ?)+$`, 
it matches a valid string of any length but takes more than 4800 ms for the below string

```
Test regex -121-test valid future_4 %$^&.
```

Invalid patterns with smaller lengths are also working fine, eg:

```
future_4%$^& , $$%%
```

Please explain why this happens and solution for the same?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: thanks for sharing your discovery. if you need help you need to ask a specific question

Comment: I think the question is posed in the title, not the body, looks like OP wants to know How to implement a timeout for the regex to match or something

Comment: This is a pattern of **catastrophic backtracking** (quantifiers inside quantifiers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always make sure your patterns are written in a linear way, that is, the adjoining subpatterns do not match the same char as the preceding pattern.

That said, your pattern, when there is no space after a word/hyphen char, turns into something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+...$` and that involves too much backtracking (I omitted a capturing group, but in your pattern, Group 1 value will also be constantly re-written, it is also hampering matching).

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` - 1 or more letters, digits, `_` or `-`
- `(?: [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - - space
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` - 1 or more letters, digits, `_` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

While [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/WZdkxB/1) causes catastrophic backtracking, [mine](https://regex101.com/r/WZdkxB/2) fails gracefully.